# Chrome developer tools not showing xhr size with request headers

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, cookies

we are optimizing our web application performance and as part of that currently working on minimize the cookie size and trying to see the results. Earlier the cookie size was huge and removed ~ 700B of unwanted data (I see a recommended size for cookie is ~ 400B) and the cookie size is ~50B. However there is no change in the XHR size in Network tab of Chrome developer tools. The size it showed before the optimization was 250B after it showing the same 250B. It seems the request headers size is not included in this size. I tried AJAX Debugger extension and no useful data out of it. Is there any other way we can measure the entire request size of http/https calls. Please share your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Fiddler Web Debugger tool and able to capture the total request size along with the headers size and also found that the Chrome Developer Tools shows only the response size in the Network tab.

Screenshot of the Fiddler with the before/after cookie optimization and chrome Network tab is attached below

[image: Screenshot of the Fiddler with the before/after cookie optimization and chrome Network tab]